# configure notification for successful ecs deployments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-sns

I have configured micro-services infrastructure on AWS ECS.

I would like to know how we can configure notifications for each successful/failure deployment.

I wish to receive the **successful** notification in the following scenario.

*when task definition is updated, the old container should be stopped & the new container is up & running.*

If a new task definition is failed & we still have the old container running, then we should receive **failure** notification.

Please let me know what are the flexible options we have in AWS keeping cost in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon ECS has recently introduced a [new feature](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/amazon-ecs-announces-the-general-availability-of-ecs-deployment-circuit-breaker/) dubbed "deployment circuit breaker" that covers that exact scenario. I would suggest you go through [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/announcing-amazon-ecs-deployment-circuit-breaker/) that has some insides about how it works including the events notifications.